# Django - TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: django

I have a django model `Project` that looks like this:

---

```
class Project(models.Model):
    slug            = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True,default="")
    project_title   = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=120)
    project_post    = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    project_cat     = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=20)
    project_thumb   = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    project_movie   = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True,default='False')
    project_views   = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,related_name='project_views',default=0)
    project_likes   = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,related_name='project_likes',default=0)
    project_date    = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

---

When I try to create a new project, I get this error:

---

```
Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.1


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1638, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1567, in _changeform_view
    change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, formsets, add)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1043, in construct_change_message
    return construct_change_message(form, formsets, add)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 495, in construct_change_message
    changed_data = form.changed_data
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 451, in changed_data
    if field.has_changed(initial_value, data_value):
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1354, in has_changed
    if len(initial) != len(data):

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/webdata/project/add/
Exception Value: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

---

Thank you

Comment: How are you creating the new instance? Is it through django-admin?

Comment: yes, through the admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with setting the default value on the ManyToMany relation for `project_views` and `project_likes`. The ManyToMany field is expecting some form of a queryset or list (since its many), but in your case you set it to `0` as int. Change your 2 fields like so (notice field default),

```
...
project_views   = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,related_name='project_views',default=[0])
project_likes   = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,related_name='project_likes',default=[0])
...
```

or as the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#default) recommends, return the value from a class method like so,

```
....
def get_zero_user():
    """
    A list of pk's you want to set for your many to many
    """
    return [0]

project_views = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='project_views', default=get_zero_user())
project_likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='project_likes', default=get_zero_user())
...
```

Hope this helps!