# How do I resolve the Django error "object of type 'int' has no len()" when creating an object in the admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm aware of what the error means, the length function is being called on an integer, whereas it only takes a string. However, the tracelog is not particularly helpful and I'm struggling to identify where this error is happening.

```
 C:\Users\callu\PycharmProjects\DjangoTests\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py, line 162, in _has_changed

            return field.has_changed(initial_value, self.data)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

     …

Local vars
C:\Users\callu\PycharmProjects\DjangoTests\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 1650, in has_changed

            if len(initial) != len(data):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It happens when I try and create a new `Post` object in the admin site so I'm assuming there's an error somewhere in my Post Model, have I created one of the fields as the wrong type?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url_link = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="post_support", default=0, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:post_detail", args=(str(self.id),))
```

Weirdly I can create a `Post` object fine from my front end, it's just when I try to use the admin site that it throws the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127107/django-typeerror-object-of-type-int-has-no-len)

Comment: Do not set int as a default value to `ManyToManyField` because it accepts list or set. There's not need to pass default value to that field so remove it.

Comment: Aaah I've set a ManyToMany string value as an integer, when I put default=0. Thanks!